# Converting a function call into a constant

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We've got a variable `a` which is computed with a function `WhatIsA()` for the sake of a for loop. `WhatIsA`'s value is known compile-time. Is there something I can do (an attribute, perhaps?) to let the compiler know it can erase the variable and place constants in place of all of its references?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1343434; i++)
{
    int a = WhatIsA(); //retval of WhatIsA does not change after compilation, ever.
    DoSomethingWithVariableA(a);
    DooooSomethingWithVariableA(a);
    DoooooooSomethingWithVariableA(a);
}
```

The original problem comes from Unity's environment.

```
private void Update()
{
    LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Terrarin");
    CollidesBottom = Raycast((Vector2)transform.position + colliderBottomLeftOffset, Vector2.right, colliderWidth, mask);
    CollidesTop = Raycast((Vector2)transform.position + colliderTopRightOffset, Vector2.left, colliderWidth, mask);
    CollidesRight = Raycast((Vector2)transform.position + colliderTopRightOffset, Vector2.down, colliderHeight, mask);
    CollidesLeft = Raycast((Vector2)transform.position + colliderBottomLeftOffset, Vector2.up, colliderHeight, mask);
}
```

`GetMask` is known compile-time, or at least it should be. The compiler might or might not optimize it. The only thing I can do myself is, perhaps, elevate mask to a field variable and compute it in the `Start` function, but then it's scope is bigger than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Set `a` inside of `Start()` or `Awake()` and reference the variable.

Comment: Any other way, given I want to avoid broadening the variable's scope?

Comment: If it's inside of a single class, what is the issue with scope?

Comment: I'm afraid what you're asking for demands a larger scope. And the next step up from a localized variable in Update() is a member variable within the class that is initialized through Start() or Awake() as Eliasar mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/8715/how-do-i-use-layermasks.html) for some deeper explanations how exactly LayerMasks work.

In short: LayerMask is basically an int value. It represents a binary 32 bit flag system where you switch on (`1`) and off (`0`) certain layer indexes. So e.g. a value

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
                                    | |
                                    | |layer1
                                    |
                                    |layer3
```

means that layer1 and layer3 should be enabled and in decimal has the value `5`.

---

So ofcourse there are options for making this layermask constant. The simplest way would be to once output

```
LayerMask mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Terrarin");
Debug.Log(mask.value);
```

which will give you the decimal representation of the layermask. And than you can simply use

```
// 256 e.g. is the layer9
// the first entry after Unity's 8 default layers
LayerMask mask = 256;
```

or if you already know the index of the wanted layer you can also simply use

```
LayerMask mask = 1 << 9;
```

Or use those [Binary -> Decimal converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter) & [Decimal -> Binary converter](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter)

---

Ofcourse you can also do that only in `Update` but why recreate it every frame? If you hardcode it anyway you could as well use a `const` or as said in the other answer simply get the value once in `Awake`.

I don't understand your concerns about the "scope" either. As long as it stays private it doesn't matter

.. in contrary: your `Update` solution allocates and destroys `mask` over and over again -> more work for the GC.

---

## However, I would NOT recommend it!

It is a very bad design choice for two reasons:

1. A later design change and you'll have to change the code. You rename the layer you have to change the code. You want to add a layer to the mask later than you first have to recalculate the values. etc...
2. It makes your code 0% flexible and reusable! Imagine you now have your Raycaster system finished. Now you want another object in the scene raycast a different layer ... So would you prefer to copy the entire script just to change the hardcoded layer (I hope not) or would you rather prefer to use the same script and simply change the layer value.

Thus, actually in my opinion the best solution would be to **never** hardcode layernames/indexes/masks at all but rather let the developer adjust it in the inspector. You can still give it a hardcoded default value though e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask mask = 256;
```

this gives you a field in the Inspector where you can simply select your layers. You could even change them during runtime for debugging reasons.